# Javascript issue while needing to insert a DIV class

Tags: javascript, css

I have a random background script that works great. Every page gets its own random bgimage.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function getImage() {
  let randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 160);
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../../SITEWIDE/assets/bgimages/" + randomInt + ".jpg')";
    document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat";// Background repeat
    document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "absolute";
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
getImage();
</script>
```

The problem I'm having is I need to treat the image with DIV class. The browser needs to see:

```
<div class="MySpecialDiv" style="background-image: url(../../main_img/slider/image1.jpg);"></div>
```

I've attempted to use document.getElementsByClassName and document.getElementById and neither works.

Ideas?

In response, I've done..

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function getImage() {
  let randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 160);
    document.getElementById("heroBg").style.backgroundImage =  = "url('../../SITEWIDE/assets/bgimages/" + randomInt + ".jpg')";
    document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat";// Background repeat
    document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "absolute";
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
}
</script>
<div class="MySpecialDiv"></div>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
getImage();
</script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function getImage() {
  let randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 160);
    document.getElementsByClassName("MySpecialDiv").style.backgroundImage = "url('../../SITEWIDE/assets/bgimages/" + randomInt + ".jpg')";
    document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat";// Background repeat
    document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "absolute";
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
}
</script>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
getImage();
</script>
```

the script just never runs. when i inspect the HTML it's clear the function getImage() doesn't execute.

Comment: Why doesn't getElementById work? It should. Can we see the code you've tried using that so we can help you debug it?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> 
function getImage() {
  let randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 160);
    document.getElementById("MySpecialDiv").style.backgroundImage  = "url('../../SITEWIDE/assets/bgimages/" + randomInt + ".jpg')";
    document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat";// Background repeat
    document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "absolute";
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
getImage();
</script>

Comment: Well, that will correctly set the background image of the div with id `MySpecialDiv`, though you're still setting the other background properties on the body instead. But according to the HTML you posted above, `MySpecialDiv` is a class, not an id. Make it an id in the HTML and it should work. (Also, please edit that code into the original post; it's hard to read when crammed into a comment like that :) )

Comment: @SwarDet: Please include relevant code in the question, not in comments.  At a quick glance, the first thing I notice is that your HTML has no element with the `id` value "MySpecialDiv".

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns array, not a single element

Comment: @David New here sorry...

the browser has to see <div class="MySpecialDiv" style="background-image: url(../../main_img/slider/image1.jpg);"></div>

Comment: @dmitri7 do you know what i would do so the browser sees the following HTML..

 <div class="MySpecialDiv" style="background-image: url(../../main_img/slider/image1.jpg);"></div>

Comment: @dmitri7 

Currently the script produces <body style="background-image: url(../../main_img/slider/image1.jpg);;">

I need  <div class="MySpecialDiv" style="background-image: url(../../main_img/slider/image1.jpg);"></div>

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your attempts are changing both the JavaScript and the HTML and are just missing each other.  The `id` you're looking for needs to match an `id` in your HTML, and that HTML needs to be in the `<body>` of the document to be visible.

Start with just your HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="MySpecialDiv"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        getImage();
    </script>
</body>
```

From there your code should be able to find and modify an element with the `id` value `"MySpecialDiv"`:

```
let myDiv = document.getElementById("MySpecialDiv");
myDiv.style.backgroundImage = '...';
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I was able to get it working via trial and error. Technically it might be sloppy but it's working as I need now. I call the DIV via ID and CLASS Here is the solution...

```
<section id="BUZZSAW" class="no-padding-top"> 
<div id="MySpecialDIV" class="MySpecialDIV"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function getImage() {
  let randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 160);
    document.getElementById('herobg').style.backgroundImage = "url('../../SITEWIDE/assets/bgimages/" + randomInt + ".jpg')";
    document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat";// Background repeat
    document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "absolute";
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
}
</script>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
getImage();
</script>
```